# Is a "src" dir required under the top-level ng2 app dir for aot?

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I'm trying to get my app running with `AOT` per the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

I execute the following `AOT` compile command from 'MyApp' dir:

```
"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p ./ng2/tsconfig-aot.json
```

And am returned the following error:

```
Error File 'C:/CODE/MyApp/ng2/src/app/app.module.ts' not found.
```

It looks like the command is expecting a 'src' dir as the first subdir under my main `ng2` app dir.  This `ng2` app exists within the context of a parent `.NET MVC` app, which has a lot of its own special dirs.  I suspect the default `ng2` parent app dir is generally named 'src' and this is causing confusion in the look up.

Do you know if there's a command option I can pass to exclude 'src' from the dir path that the compiler is attempting to execute against?  Or if there's another `AOT` workaround for this or if I'm doing something incorrectly here?